# How do I get a java application to subscribe to an NServiceBus publisher?

Tags: java, .net, interop, messaging, nservicebus

I've asked Google and searched through the NServiceBus website and forums, but I can't seem to find any prescriptive guidance on how I would write a Java application to subscribe to a publisher. Does anyone have any such link or experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This scenario is not well supported out of the box - you'll need to do some infrastructure munging yourself. In general, look at how the proxy is built, and add some gateway-style HTTP communication in the mix, or expose that with a standard .NET webservice.

Answer (score 3):

You could manually send the subscribe message to the publisher over MSMQ, the publisher would then send any relevant messages to your java subscribers input queue. But you would need to receive those manually also.

I guess you're then committed to using MSMQ as your transport layer for your entire bus also.

Comment: If that's the only way then I guess that's ok. Was hoping to hear from someone that's tried it though.